# Altbeacon Library: Battery Status of Beacons

Tags: android, altbeacon

ich have a problem with getting the battery status of my Blue Up beacons.

with

```
beaconArray[i].getDataFields().get(0).byteValue()
```

I only get 0 as a result even though the managing app the status is over 90%.

Does that mean that the Blue Up beacon doesn't support the battery status information?

Thx for answering!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all beacon vendors use the AltBeacon data field to advertise battey level.  (Radius Networks beacons among other vendors are known to support this.). Other vendors sometimes use a GATT service that requires connection and reading a characteristic to get the battery level.

Because the variations on vendor implementations is unlimited, the Android Beacon Library only supports open published specifications for reading battery level like AltBeacon and Eddystone.  (iBeacon has no such support, although some vendors have proprietary extensions.)

Your best bet is to go through any available docs from Blue Up to see if they document how reading the battery level works.